# R Blastula acknowledgement of receipt

Tags: r, email, blastula

I would like to know if it's possible to get an acknowledgement of receipt after sending an email under R with the Blastula package? And if not with another package?

Thanks in advance !
Have a nice day !

Comment: It's generally not possible. When you send an email and the mail server accepts it, it will queue it and try to deliver it to the final mail server. It will retry, sometimes for days. When it cannot deliver the email, it *should* send a delivery status notification email to the sender (bounce). If you don't get that, you can assume it was delivered, but you still have no idea if it went to spam or was read.

Comment: okay, thanks! Maybe I found a roundabout solution. I send  a mail in my mailbox and I create a rules, when I reveive this particulary mail, it is immediately transferred to an other recipient !